# What is Maduro's approval among Venezuelan expatriates?

Tags: public-opinion, venezuela

The president of Venezuela, Nicolas Maduro, has an approval rating of around 20% (e.g. [this survey](https://es.scribd.com/document/388786757/Resultados-Encuesta-Meganalisis-Septiembre-2018-Publicacion)). These studies do have flaws, since some may not properly account for his support in the lowest-income neighborhoods, which tend to be more chavista—for instance, telephone surveys will underrepresent people who don't have telephones—but it's a baseline.

However,  [large numbers of citizens](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/world/wp/2018/03/02/feature/i-cant-go-back-venezuelans-are-fleeing-their-crisis-torn-country-en-masse/?utm_term=.daddd2769a59)  have immigrated to other countries over the last few years. This subset might not be representative of Venezuelan approval of Maduro as a whole. For instance, they might be more in favor of Maduro, because lower-income people might be more desperate to leave the country. Or they might be  more against Maduro, since higher income people are more likely to be able to leave, or because people who dislike Maduro might be more eager to leave a country governed by him. Further, since the people who've left Venezuela, at about 1 million, are about 3% of the country's population and possibly a larger percentage of its adult population, their absence could influence Maduro's overall approval rating.

Has there been any research that measures Maduro's approval rating among the Venezuelan community abroad? If so, how high is it?

Comment: I think their approval rate is near to nonexistent. If your life situation is so bad that you have to leave your country, politics must be bad. It's very natural process: If the people are well, they like the government, as soon as they suffer they despise it.

Comment: May be ask this guy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregory_Wilpert

Comment: @H2ONaCl - Perhaps he'd know, yes. I'm looking for some systematic information, though.

Comment: @Miep - You might leave a country for financial reasons without blaming the government. Maybe some blame the US for instance, as Maduro does, or global economic trends beyond Maduro's control.

Comment: @Obie2.0 That was a good joke Obie and completely fictional statement. Ask several millions of migrants leaving the country in a terrible health state where they don't even have money to bury their family members who don't make it...

Comment: @FrankLabry - Which statement was fictional? "You might leave a country for financial reasons without blaming the government." Well, apparently at least one person (this Gregory Wilpert) left Venezuela for job-related reasons and remained a chavista. So that's clearly not fictional. Or that some people blame the US or the economy for their situation...well, I can't prove it, but Maduro's relatively small Venezuelan base likes to blame the US or sometimes the global economy. At least some of them probably have left the country - supporting Maduro doesn't immunize them to his economic crisis.

Comment: Or maybe you've mistaken my attempt to ask a careful, objective question looking for data, rather than simply assuming I know the statistical breakdown of political views among Venezuelans living abroad, for personal support of Maduro. If I were a chavista, I'd be saying that he had a 68% approval rating, based on the results of his 2018 "election," not 20%.

Comment: @miep Among French living abroad, Macron is much more popular than among French living in France.  Living abroad does not automatically imply opposition to the regime of the home country.

Comment: @gerrit read my comment: "If your life situation is so bad that you have to leave your country[...]" The french you are referring to left france out of free will, not because they didn't know if they could eat tomorrow.

Comment: @miep Most emigrants probably oppose the regime, there may also be some who flee yet blame the opposition (i.e. refugees from an actual civil war such as in Syria may well be supportive of the regime, but flee when the regime is no longer in control).